# Google Charts: AnnotationChart multiple Vertical axis?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am using the annotation chart from google here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart

The reason I am using it is so the user can scroll through the data and select parts of the data.

The problem is I really need a way to have multiple vertical scales since on some of my graphs we can have up to 3 series that are very different magnitudes and it makes it hard to see the smaller series.

I've been searching and reading the docs and I can't seem to find any mention of this for the annotation chart, is this possible or have I chosen the wrong library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found a solution here: https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1827

I'm still having issues with more than 2 vAxis, they start to overlap.

The last comment here fixes the overlap issues: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/ncHJolrRT7o